Alexa live radio skill without enable
I'm new to Alexa Skills development and I have some basic skills working. I am having trouble finding information about how to register a live stream skill that does not need enabling via the store first.
In the same way a radio station can play via tune-in, but I do not want to register via tune-in. Thankyou
